# LDAP integration with drupal

Tags: 6

I have a LDAP server and my website runs on drupal 6. So i want users from LDAP to access my website using their login details. Which module is preferable for this. i want users to be created on drupal and authentication to happen with LDAP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you already tried this module?
http://drupal.org/project/ldap_integration

We use this on our (drupal) user control panel to let user authenticate from our LDAP database. Personally I haven't installed it myself, I'm using the drupal 7 version, which works great to!
http://drupal.org/project/ldap

Comment: Yeah have installed ldap_integration and struggling to get it working. Any tips regarding that module?

Comment: What exact problems are you having? Problems connecting to LDAP?

Comment: i was seeing the code and saw that it is breaking at this step.     $result = $_ldapauth_ldap->search($base_dn, $filter); . what all should i check to solve this